# Does ember-data really support nested urls?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a top level session object that can have many speakers under it.

My REST ish endpoint allows me to get all the sessions like so

/sessions/

I can get all the speakers for a given session like so

/sessions/1/speakers/

With the current version of ember-data I can see it's trying to find all the speakers with this url

/speakers/

Using the data model below

```
CodeCamp.Session = DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  speakers: DS.hasMany('CodeCamp.Speaker',{nested: true})                                                          
});

CodeCamp.Speaker = DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  session: DS.belongsTo('CodeCamp.Session',{nested: true})
});
```

I added the "nested:true" part because I wanted ember-data to build the required

/sessions/%@/speakers/

But this didn't happen -

I know I can define a url manually

```
CodeCamp.Speaker.reopenClass({
  url: 'sessions/%@/speakers/'
});
```

But in doing so I will need to roll my own "buildURL" method in the base REST adapter so it looks for a format like this and adds the parent id when necessary (and I'd rather not do this if possible)

Does ember-data have support for something like this out of the box or will I be forced to write a great deal of code myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{nested: true}` is not yet a feature. [The pull request is still open.](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/257)

Override & use the adapter's [`findQuery()`](https://github.com/emberjs/data#findquery) to make a GET request with such a URL.

Also, if your server is Rails (and maybe this works for other frameworks), it is possible to keep the request URL single-level, by passing the parent ID as a querystring param:

```
/speakers?session_id=1
```

Comment: thanks - I was able to use this as a work-around for now (hope to see this in the final ember.js 1.0 release or soon after)